# Can't get this query to work. Mysql update select another query then update

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

```
UPDATE `tombaldi_2bj3de9ad`.`catalog_product_option_type_value`
SET `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`option_id` = '72'
WHERE `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`option_id` IN
(SELECT  `catalog_product_option_type_value`.`option_id` 
FROM `tombaldi_2bj3de9ad`.`catalog_product_option_type_title` 
INNER JOIN `tombaldi_2bj3de9ad`.`catalog_product_option_type_value` ON catalog_product_option_type_title.option_type_id = catalog_product_option_type_value.option_type_id
 WHERE (
    CONVERT( `title` USING utf8 ) LIKE '%initials%'
 ))
```

I get the error

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'catalog_product_option_type_value' for update in FROM clause

Trying to solve this one. Have researched and tried and tried again.

Comment: CONVERT? Can you imagine how horrible this is?

Comment: Also, you seem to have an entirely redundant subquery here !?!?

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can't use same table in query during update,this can be done by giving the new alias to your subquery

```
UPDATE tombaldi_2bj3de9ad.catalog_product_option_type_value 
SET catalog_product_option_type_value.option_id = '72' 
WHERE catalog_product_option_type_value.option_id 
IN (SELECT t.option_id  
FROM (
SELECT catalog_product_option_type_value.option_id 
FROM tombaldi_2bj3de9ad.catalog_product_option_type_title 
INNER JOIN tombaldi_2bj3de9ad.catalog_product_option_type_value
 ON catalog_product_option_type_title.option_type_id = catalog_product_option_type_value.option_type_id 
WHERE ( CONVERT( title USING utf8 ) LIKE '%initials%' )
)  t
)
```

Or even better to use join in your update query

```
UPDATE 
  tombaldi_2bj3de9ad.catalog_product_option_type_value cv
  JOIN tombaldi_2bj3de9ad.catalog_product_option_type_title  ct
  ON(ct.option_type_id = cv.option_type_id )
SET
  cv.option_id = '72' 
WHERE CONVERT(ct.title USING utf8) LIKE '%initials%'
```

Comment: I would vote this up if I could. This helped and did exactly what I was trying to.